# How can you generate or export log reports for selenium ide test cases?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

After the creation of test suits how can we export the test/log reports into a file,the type of file that it needs to be exported to maybe .txt or .pdf or anything else too?

was trying to export test results or log reports into a file

Comment: Refer this - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)